# QWidget does not accept values bigger than approximately 23000 for setFixedSize

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

This code exits without any error while the computer get's out of ram for this app I guess; it takes around 2 gigs of ram and my laptop has 6; it works only for values like 23000 or smaller for the QWidget's fixedSize. How to create a QWidget with a size of 1000000 for width and height without consuming so much of ram?

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(1000000, 1000000)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit:
I'm coming from WPF/C# world and there it is possible to have a Canvas with a big size without any problem or ram shortage. For instance, one could have a map with a size of 30000 for width and height then it is possible with some implementations to zoom in and out for a good overall view super fast and without ram consumption this high as Qt (in WPF my final app with lots of items in it takes around 21 megabytes of ram with a Canvas which has 1 million pixels for width and height; size doesn't matter there). It was surprising to find out by increasing the size of a QWidget the ram consumption goes higher.

I'm new to Qt and so far what I understood is that to have a big map with zoom capability we need to use Scene and View. So it is doable but with different approach compared to WPF.

Comment: Why do you want a widget that is 1,000,000 by 1,000,000? Maybe there's a better way to solve what you want.

Comment: If a map is your goal, Qt has [example code](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-maps-example.html).

Comment: @JarMan Thank you **Scene** and **View** was the solution.